# How can I get rid of this extra character ? in xml read

Tags: xml

There is an extra character appearing at the beginning of my xml file which in turn causes an error for my parse method. I am using InputStreamReader to read the file from a URL.

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

my code, if interested

```
public class Client {

private static final String TAG = "Client";
public Client(){

}

InputStream executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters){

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
    try{
        //Create connection

        url = new URL(targetURL);
        //Log.i(TAG,"Connecting to : "+targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);



        //get response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line ="";

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);

        }


        return is;


    }catch(Exception e){
        //Log.i(TAG,"Unable to create connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }finally {

          if(connection != null) {
            //Log.i(TAG,"Disconnecting");
            connection.disconnect(); 
          }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What encoding are you reading the file with? What language is this and on what platform?

Comment: @Oded I am using "UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

That is a so called BOM, (byte order mark) and you should use an xml parser instance to read the xml file that can deal with it.

Comment: which xml parsers are able to hand this?

Comment: I have used dom4j for such purposes. But there are dozens of good Java XML libraries.